# Try to load precompiled .so Android NDK (Exception java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library)

Tags: java, android, android-ndk

I try to build an Android Project (ndk-build).

I´d like to use a precompiled library in my project. (libdemo.so)

Android.mk:

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_CPPFLAGS := -fexceptions
APP_ABI=armeabi armeabi-v7a
```

Application.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
TARGET_ARCH_ABI := armeabi-v7a

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libdemo
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libdemo.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := native-lib
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := native-lib.cpp
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libdemo
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

MainActivity:

```
android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // Used to load the 'native-lib' library on application startup.
     static {
        System.loadLibrary("demo");
        System.loadLibrary("native-lib");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sample_text);
        Log.d("TAG", stringFromJNI());
    }

    /**
     * A native method that is implemented by the 'native-lib' native library,
     * which is packaged with this application.
     */
    public native String stringFromJNI();
}
```

But I get the following exception on build:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "/Users/John/Documents/Apps/LibTest/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libdemo.so" not found
```

The file exists on the provided path. I think the path at all isn´t correct.
Why is there the path from my desktop pc? There should be a path from my device or?

Anyone here to help?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the question by myself.

I don´t knew that ndk-build isn´t processed automatically.
I had go to my project folder (folder where jni is present) and does ndk-build manually.

After that the libs are compiled and copied automatically in the /libs folder.

Now just build and run the app as usual and everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this was caused by missing `SONAME` tag on the generated shared library. When this tag is missing, the Android build process will use the absolute path to the library instead of the device-specific path.

One has to explicitly specify the SONAME either via `-soname` or `-install_name` (macOS-specific) parameter to the linker.

For instance, this can happen when building shared libs from Go source, as mentioned in [https://github.com/golang/go/issues/17807\#issuecomment-259930881](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/17807%5C#issuecomment-259930881).